# SQL Server: replace year of datetime with current year in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I am selecting data using the following stored procedure with dateDT being saved as datetime.

Can someone here tell me how I can replace the year in the below Convert results so that this is always the current year (independent of the year it is saved under in the table) ?

```
SELECT      dateID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dateDT, 106) AS dateDT,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateDT, 126) AS dateDTShort,
            countries,
            regions
FROM        DaysFixed
WHERE       countries LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
OR          regions LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
ORDER BY    dateID
FOR XML PATH('datesDT'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the year after the conversion.  Here are examples for your date formats:

```
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), dateDT, 106) + CAST(year(getdate() as varchar(4)) AS dateDT,
        STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateDT, 126), 1, 4, CAST(year(getdate() as varchar(4)))
             ) AS dateDTShort,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great ! What does STUFF do ?

Comment: Stuff replaces a specific part of a string (defined by position) with another string.  See the documentation:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2012-04-27 14:00:39.343'

SELECT CAST(
        STUFF(
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @dt,121)
              ,1, 4, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
             )
           AS DATETIME)

 Result:  2014-04-27 14:00:39.343
```